# What are the Formspring authentication URLs? (OAuth iPhone)

Tags: iphone, authentication, ios4, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to gain authorization to Formspring using the OAuthConsumer found at https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer.

I've looked at many examples and thoroughly Googled for the answer, but I can't find the URL's you need to call for gaining access to the user's data.  URL's for authentication, token requesting, etc.  I imagine there should be something like: formspring.me/authentication or formspring.me/get_token_request etc, but I can't find anything.

Where can I look for these or if you know them what are they?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is currently in beta. You need to request access at the following URL:
http://www.formstack.com/forms/?844272-7VPxuC7gnR

If you are granted access to the API, you'll be sent an email with more details on how to connect.

Comment: By the sound of things he already has access to the API. The endpoints are not very well documented. I have access to it, so I'll go take a look and see what I can find...

Comment: All the necessary information is here: http://dev.formspring.me/. The only difference is the endpoint, which is beta-api instead of api while it's still in beta. This is information that should be disclosed in the emails you receive once you're accepted into the beta. If it's not, definitely send us a note at http://formspring.me/api